# How to sort the keys of a dictionary by the sum of the inner value of its nested dictionary elements?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested, key

So I've looked into some similar questions but I couldn't find an answer, suitable for my problem. I have a nested dictionary and I need to sort the keys of the whole dictionary by the sum of the values of the nested dictionaries, but in reversed order:

So from:

```
dict = {Sarah : {apple: 1, pear: 2}, John: {tomato: 5, cucumber: 5}, Dany: {carrot: 1}}
```

I need to get to:

```
dict = {Dany: {carrot:1}, Sarah: {apple: 1, pear: 2}, John: {tomato: 5, cucumber: 5}}
```

I figured I could maybe do this with `dict(sorted(), key, reverse=True)`, but I am unable to formulate correctly the key because I don't understand how can I access the inner values of the nested dictionaries.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have sufficiently high Python (3.7+) version where insertion-order of keys is preserved you can do:

```py
dct = {
    "Sarah": {"apple": 1, "pear": 2},
    "John": {"tomato": 5, "cucumber": 5},
    "Dany": {"carrot": 1},
}

dct = dict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda k: sum(k[1].values())))
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Dany': {'carrot': 1}, 'Sarah': {'apple': 1, 'pear': 2}, 'John': {'tomato': 5, 'cucumber': 5}}
```

---

If not, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

dct = OrderedDict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda k: sum(k[1].values())))
print(dct)
```

Comment: Yes, I have the 3.10 version and your first suggestion does the trick! Thank you!  However, I still don't understand what k[1] stands for exactly. I know we introduce k with the lambda, but I am missing on the [1] part. Could you, please explain?

Comment: @habitant `dct.items()` items returns tuples of (key1, value1), (key2, value2), ... so `lambda k: sum(k[1].values())` returns sum of valueN.items() where value is the inner dict.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sorted(dict, key=lambda x: sum(dict[x].values()))
```